# Parsing Sentences to Words in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, parsing, sql-server-2012, character

I imported data into SQL server using a CSV and now I'm trying to query through the data but unable to do so because SQL reads the values as 1 string.

**BookTitles** <-- DATA

ID : Title

1 : Cat in the hat

2 : Harry potter

3 : Lord of the Rings

4 : The Art of war

5 : Inside the cave

6: Incorporate

**For instance i cant use the query:** <-- QUERY

SELECT * FROM BookTitles

WHERE Title = '%in%'

**I expect to get:** <-- EXPECTED

1 : Cat in the hat

5: Inside the cave

6: Incorporate

I am getting no results with the query above. Is there a way to use SQL to read all texts as individual words?

Comment: Please share the sample data as it is available in your table and expected result

Comment: share the sample data? Like attach the CSV? The CSV contains a lot of rows.. I  thought it'd better to show a bit of it

Comment: Just add couple of rows and your expected result for given data

Comment: the above query won't work .... it should be `title like '%in%'`

Comment: Add LIKE instead of =

Comment: Do I get this correctly? What you show us as sample data is one sinlge chunk of text? Or is this stored to a table row-wise (line be line)?

Comment: Yes you did! Thank you

Comment: @CastilloCaleb you have to split your text on line breaks. (`char(13)` and `char(10)`. No time at the moment... I'll come back later. But this will be answered by this time probably

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
SELECT * FROM BookTitles
WHERE Title like '%in%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM BookTitles
WHERE charindex('in',Title) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The first advise is: Do not use this data in this format!

Split this to lines and store them separately. Do not even try to use queries against this bunch of words, which is not even 1.NF...

Use something along these line to

- Split your text in lines and
- shift them into a (tolerant) staging table
- Continue from this staging table and shift the data into a well-designed target table

Try it out:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Data NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('ID : Title

1 : Cat in the hat

2 : Harry potter

3 : Lord of the Rings

4 : The Art of war

5 : Inside the cave

6: Incorporate');

DECLARE @StagingTable TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(MAX), Title NVARCHAR(250));

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(Data,CHAR(13),CHAR(10)) AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),CHAR(10),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS DataInLines
    FROM @tbl
)
,SingleLines AS
(
    SELECT l.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SingleLine
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY DataInLines.nodes('/x[text()]') AS A(l)
)
INSERT INTO @StagingTable(ID,Title)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(SingleLine,CHARINDEX(':',SingleLine)-1))) 
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(SingleLine,CHARINDEX(':',SingleLine)+1,1000)))
FROM SingleLines;

SELECT * FROM @StagingTable
```